# C# Windows Form - How to Reuse an Object from a Different Button Click Event

Tags: c#, winforms, hp-quality-center

I am building a Windows Form where I am connecting to HP Quality Center OTA. I am able to login to the system but after logging out when I click to the Login button the previous instance of the object doesn't get reinitialized. Is there a way to reuse the same object or is there a different approach I should be taking? Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TDAPIOLELib;

namespace TestLab
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    static TDConnection tdc = new TDConnection();
    static String qcUrl = "https://serveraddress/qcbin";
    static string uid;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void login_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uid = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter your User ID", "User ID", " ", 0, 0);
        string pwd1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter your password", "Password", " ", 0, 0);

   //     TDConnection tdc = new TDConnection();
        tdc.InitConnectionEx(qcUrl);
        tdc.Login(uid, pwd1);

        label1.Text = " ";
        label1.Text = uid + " logged into HPQC.";

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void logout_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tdc.Logout();
        tdc.Disconnect();
        tdc = null;
        label1.Text = " ";
        label1.Text = uid + " logged out of HPQC.";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you set the variable tdc to null then you need to call new TDConnection again. I don't understand why you have commented out that line in the Login code

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for feedback. Yes, in one iteration I had used the commented code inside the login_button1_Click function, but then when I clicked logout button, it didn't recognize the tdc object as it was out of scope. So I made tdc as a static object outside of these two functions. Now I can login and logout first time but after logging out when I click login button again, and enter the id and password, I get the error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: There is no need to make tdc static, but you need to declare it at the global level to be able to use it in two different methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Logout code you set the global variable `tdc` to null. Of course this means that you need to reinitialize it with a call to `new TDConnection`

You seems to have two options.

1. Remove the line that sets the tdc variable to null in the logout
   code. Leave everything else unchanged
2. Do not initialize the variable tdc at the global level but just
   everytime you enter the login code and leave the line that sets the variable tdc to null in the logout code.

Consider also that these kind of objects usually implements the IDisposable interface. If it is the same with your TDConnection class then it is probably better to call the Dispose method in the logout code

Comment: For the second option: if I don't declare it as a static variable, how will the logout code know that object as it is out of scope? Thanks for the tip on Dispose method, I believe it is available in this API. I will check and will use it after tdc.Disconnect(). Thank you.

Comment: If the variable is declared at the global class scope then it is available in all methods of that class. Static means that every instance of the Form1 class use the same tdc. You need just the visibility on the declaration in different methods, you don't need the same instance of tdc in many instances of Form1. What happen if you remove the static keyword?

Comment: Hi Steve, for the second option after removing "static" from tdc object, I get error message after clicking the Login button the second time (after logout): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I would like to add here: when tdc = null; statement is commented out, then the NullReferenceException error is not observed.

Comment: The basic problem is the setting to null, static has nothing to do with the problem of a NRE. Also if you keep the variable static but set it to null then you cannot use it again until you reinitilize if with new